# Android app to run actions on Windows computer

Tags: windows, android, automation

I have an Android phone and a Windows 10 computer. I would like to have an app on my phone that I could use to run commands on my Windows computer. I would like to define in advance what kind of commands I want to run, by specifying a command line with arguments. I want to create buttons on the app for each command. Then when I press the button on the Android app, it causes the computer to run that command line, and hopefully also tells me whether it succeeded or failed.

Does an Android app like that exist?

Comment: Install an SSH server on Windows and an SSH client on Android.

Comment: Lots and lots of ways to setup it. SSH is not necessarily the most secure one. It all depends on how easy it should be to setup, if you prefer free or more robust solutions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One can use [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Remote_Desktop):

- gratis
- has a client for Android
- limitation: pain to read on Android if your Windows resolution is high.

Answer (score 0):

I found [UnifiedRemote](https://www.unifiedremote.com/). It seems to support this use case, though documentation is sparse.